# increment only on a number on a single <li> in a for with VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vue-component, v-for

I want that in my v-for, when I click the UP button, the li which is linked to the button increases his State by +1.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
Vue.component('app', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            messages: '',
            state: 0,
            id: 0,
            todo: [],
            columns: ["todo", "doing", "done"],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        upElement: function (id) {
            this.id
            this.state++;
        },
        removeElement: function (key) {
            this.todo.splice(key, 1);
        },
    },

    template: `
        <ul>
            <li v-if="state === 0" v-for="(item, key) in todo" v-bind:messages="todo.messages + todo.state + todo.id" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="key">
                <span>{{item.messages}}</span></br>
                <button v-on:click="upElement">UeP</button>
                <button v-on:click="removeElement(key)">remove</button>
            </li>
        </ul>=
    `,
})
```

I wanted to put an id to target the li but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the item object directly to your `upElement` function and modify the state property.

```
Vue.component('app', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            messages: '',
            state: 0,
            id: 0,
            todo: [],
            columns: ["todo", "doing", "done"],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        upElement: function (item) {
            item.state++;
        },
        removeElement: function (key) {
            this.todo.splice(key, 1);
        },
    },

    template: `
                    <ul>
                        <li v-if="state === 0" v-for="(item, key) in todo" v-bind:messages="todo.messages + todo.state + todo.id" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="key">
                            <span>{{item.messages}}</span></br>
                            <button v-on:click="upElement(item)">UeP</button>
                            <button v-on:click="removeElement(key)">remove</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>=
    `,
})
```